# Add text to end on LONGTEXT with mysql commands

Tags: mysql, subquery

Actually use a command for add some text to one field LONGTEXT

```
UPDATE table SET field = CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 USING UTF8), filed, 'SOME TEXT ADD') WHERE other_filed = 'somestatus'
```

But I like modify my strategy for add this.

I need check if exists 'SOME TEXT ADD' and if exist made nothing, and if not exists, add text.

I see some articles on Stackoverflow, but all speak about other question, similar but not of the same content

As a last cartridge, I put two works

First work for add 'SOME TEXT ADD' and after user REPLACE for duplicate text.

```
UPDATDE table SET field = REPLACE(field, 'SOME TEXT ADD SOME TEXT ADD', 'SOME TEXT ADD');
```

But this is very wrong way.

I'm using MariaDB 10.X (or MySQL 5.7 >)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use directly the where condition for check if exist eg using like

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 USING UTF8), filed, 'SOME TEXT ADD') 
WHERE other_filed = 'somestatus'
and field like '%SOME TEXT ADD%';
```

Comment: if use `like (%SOME TEXT ADD%);` get error `like ('%SOME TEXT ADD%');` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near